# Failed to retrieve application signup event message

Tags: wso2-stratos

Being new to stratos I am getting the above error continuously thrown on my terminal .  Error came after running the stratos.sh script.  log is as follows

`ERROR {org.apache.stratos.messaging.message.receiver.application.signup.ApplicationSignUpEventMessageDelegator} -  Failed to retrieve application signup event message
java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
at org.apache.stratos.messaging.message.processor.application.signup.CompleteApplicationSignUpsMessageProcessor.process 
(CompleteApplicationSignUpsMessageProcessor.java:79)`

Comment: Can you include the complete stack trace?

Comment: I edited the question, included the stack trace..